# Is there a tool that would filter elements of a response based on some rules?

Tags: java, spring, web-services, spring-boot, spring-rest

I have a requirement where a REST/WS response object needs to filter out some of its elements (remove them altogether) based on some rules, like what the end user is authorized to see. Instead of statically doing this binding in some class, is there a utility too that would do this? I am using Spring Boot and its Spring framework.

Comment: why you dont want to use filter?

Comment: With 2.5k reputation and 8 gold badges you should know better than to make an off topic request for a tool/library recommendation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just need to filter elements in a collection (list, set, map) then you could use Spring-Security's `@PostFilter` annotation.

@See Spring Security Reference: [Chapter Filtering using @PreFilter and @PostFilter](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html/el-access.html#filtering-using-prefilter-and-postfilter)